# Decoding URL in Go

Tags: go

I am calling an API that is returning a URL in a UTF-8 encoded XML document. The parsing is returning something like `http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.test.com` and I want to convert it to `http://www.test.com`.

I'm struggling to find the right way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: this code does what I need, but would have thought there would have been a pre-built function that does something similar to this website: https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

```
    for _, user := range x.Users {
        a := strings.Replace(user.Username, "&#x3a;", ":", -1)
        b := strings.Replace(a, "&#x2f;", "/", -1)
        fmt.Println(b)
    }
```

Comment: "The parsing is returning something like" --- what "the parsing" exactly means here? If you parse XML right then you should get the original data that does not need any extra processing.

Comment: Ah - thanks. Thank helped me realize the API is double encoding. `http&#x26;&#x23;x3a&#x3b;&#x26;&#x23;x2f&#x3b;&#x26;&#x23;x2f&#x3b;www.test.com` is being returned. I don't have control over the API so I need to basically run it through another round of decoding in my app and not sure best way to do that.

Comment: "not sure best way to do that." --- so don't do it "the best way" (especially that absolute "the best" does not exist). Implement it in any way that works, then come here if you have any problem with your implementation.

Comment: Sorry man - I'm clearly frustrating you. I don't know how else to say the problem I'm having: I don't know how to convert `http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.test.com` to `http://www.test.com` in Go. That's all I'm asking for help on. I've read through net/url and other encoding packages but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `&#x3a;` - everything that starts with `&#x` then 2 hexadecimal characters, then `;` should be ascii-decoded. Take a regex or string functions for that.

Comment: Thanks - I'll put an example of what works in the question for clarification. I had thought there would have been an easier way since websites like https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ did exactly what I wanted. I figured there would be a prebuilt method for it. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: You are not dealing with URL encoding. You are dealing with XML escaping. That your content happens to be a URL is irrelevant. Also, make sure that this is really a bug in the API, such that every URL is double escaped. If the API returns user generated content, for instance, someone saved garbage. You can't fix that reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `html.UnescapeString("http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www.test.com")` which results in `http://www.test.com`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I don't know how that didn't come up in any of my searches. Thank you!